# max-width of 100px vs width of 100px , why max-width is shorter than width?

Tags: html, css

I want to understand the difference of those two thank you

max-width:100px
[image]

width:100px
[image]

```
body{
      max-width: 1080px;
      width: 1080px;
      background-color: floralwhite;
      margin:0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }

p{
      width:100px; /* and max-width of 100px; */
      padding: 20px;
      margin:0px;
      float:left;
    }
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the `width` property as being more strict than the `max-width` property.

- Width says: "You should be this width and **nothing** else."
- Max-width says: "Be whatever width you want, just not bigger than this width."

You can see this with the demo you provided. The *natural* width of the boxes is around 50px, not bigger than 100px so `max-width` doesn't really care. However, `width` sees that the boxes aren't 100px and so sets them to be 100px.

Answer (score 1):

The `max-width` attribute only uses the entire `width` if needed, depending on the content or `padding`. The `width` attribute will always use the specified amount (in your case `100px`).

[See my example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/topr/z8q3x3Lr/)

You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/):

*[max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)* - *The max-width CSS property is used to set the maximum width of an element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified by max-width.*

*[width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)* - *The width property specifies the width of an element. By default, the property defines the width of the content area. If box-sizing is set to border-box, it instead determines the width of the border area.*

Answer (score 1):

The `max-width` property is used to set the maximum width of an element.

This prevents the value of the `width` property from becoming larger than `max-width`.

**Note**: The value of the `max-width` property overrides `width`.

So if both are specified in the styles then if the width property is less than the `max-width` then the `width` property will be applied, else the `max-width` property will be applied instead.

I think if you specify the `max-width` only then the width property will default to  'auto' ,  but will still be restricted to the `max-width` specified.